# Invalid default: Spring data elastic search with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276066/enableelasticsearchrepositories-exception) question and the solution given there did not fix  my problem.

I am using `Spring-boot 1.3.2.RELEASE` along with `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`.

My configuration :

```
@Configuration 
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.hoardings.backend")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {
     @Resource
     private Environment environment; 
     @Bean
     public Client client() {
         TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
         TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port")));
         client.addTransportAddress(address);        
         return client;
     }

     @Bean
     public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
         return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
     }
}
```

and the properites :

```
elasticsearch.host=localhost
elasticsearch.port=9200
```

I get the following exception(same exception mentioned in the above question) :

```
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:611) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.registerDefaultValues(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:69) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.doVisitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:57) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.doVisitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:67) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:48) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:279) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

I checked the question mentioned above and added dependency for `spring-data-commons`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but still I get the same error.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: @RahulSharma did you read the stack trace?

Comment: You don't need to add the `data-commons` dependency. Spring Boot provides some auto configurations for elasticsearch, so you do not need to add the configurations. Just remove all the configurations and use `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes` properties in your `application.properties`